# How to count frequency in gensim.Doc2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am training a model with `gensim`, my corpus is many short sentences, and each sentence has a frequency which indicates times it occurs in total corpus. I implement it as follow, as you can see, I just choose to do repeat `freq` times. Any way, if the data is small, it should work, but when data grows, **the frequency can be very large, it costs too much memory** and my machine cannot afford it.

So 
1. **can I just count the frequency in every record instead of repeat `freq` times?** 2. **Or any other ways to save memory?**

```
class AddressSentences(object):
    def __init__(self, raw_path, path):
        self._path = path

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path) as fi:
            headers = next(fi).split(",")
            i_address, i_freq = headers.index("address"), headers.index("freq")
            index = 0
            for line in fi:
                cols = line.strip().split(",")
                freq = cols[i_freq]
                address = cols[i_address].split()
                # Here I do repeat
                for i in range(int(freq)):
                    yield TaggedDocument(address, [index])
                index += 1

print("START %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
train_corpus = list(AddressSentences("/data/corpus.csv"))
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(size=50, min_count=2, iter=55)
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
print("END %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
```

corpus is something like this:

```
address,freq
Cecilia Chapman 711-2880 Nulla St.,1000
The Business Centre,1000
61 Wellfield Road,500
Celeste Slater 606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street,600
Theodore Lowe Azusa New York 39531,700
Kyla Olsen Ap #651-8679 Sodales Av.,300
```

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Comment: @MattiLyra sorry, I am just editing my questions

Comment: So just to double check you want to `N` `TaggegDocuments` where `N` is equal to the last number on the line? What are you doing with the `TaggedDocuments`, the yield only creates a single one at a time, so you must be caching them somewhere else. Do they need to be separate objects?

Comment: @MattiLyra but `model.build_vocab` and `model.train` only accept `list`, so I repeat `N` times in the `list`

Comment: The items in the list can be a reference to the same `object` they don't necessarily need to be separate object instances, which means that you're memory consumption is equal to 1 object, instead of 1000 for the first row. But if you can do that depends on what the downstream code does to those objects.

Comment: Also why do you need to repeat the same address `1000` times?

Answer (score 0):

Two options for your exact question:

(1)

You don't need to reify your corpus iterator into a fully in-memory list, with your line:

```
    train_corpus = list(AddressSentences("/data/corpus.csv"))
```

The gensim Word2Vec model can use your iterable-object directly as its corpus, since it implements `__iter__()` (and thus can be iterated over multiple times). So you can just do:

```
    train_corpus = AddressSentences("/data/corpus.csv")
```

Then each line will be read, and each repeated TaggedDocument re-`yield()`ed, without requiring the full set in memory.

(2)

Alternatively, in such cases you may sometimes just want to write a separate routine that takes your original file, and rather than directly yielding `TaggedDocument`s, does the repetition to create a tangible file on disk which includes the repetitions. Then, use a more simple iterable reader to stream that (already-repeated) dataset into your model.

A negative of this approach, in this particular case, is that it would increase the amount of (likely relatively laggy) disk-IO. However, if the special processing your iterator is doing is more costly – such as regex-based tokenization – this sort of process-and-rewrite can help avoid duplicate work by the model later. (The model needs to scan your corpus once for vocabulary-discovery, then again `iter` times for training – so any time-consuming work in your iterator will be done redundantly, and may be the bottleneck that keeps other training threads idle waiting for data.)

But after those two options, some Doc2Vec-specific warnings:

Repeating documents like this may not benefit the Doc2Vec model, as compared to simply iterating over the full diverse set. It's the tug-of-war interplay of contrasting examples which cause the word-vectors/doc-vectors in Word2Vec/Doc2Vec models to find useful relative arrangements.

Repeating exact documents/word-contexts is a plausible way to "overweight" those examples, but even if that's really what you want, and would help your end-goals, it'd be better to shuffle those repeats through the whole set.

Repeating one example consecutively is like applying the word-cooccurrences of that example like a jackhammer on the internal neural-network, without any chance for interleaved alternate examples to find a mutually-predictive weight arrangement. The iterative gradient-descent optimization through all diverse examples ideally works more like gradual water-driven erosion & re-deposition of values.

That suggests another possible reason to take the second approach, above: after writing the file-with-repeats, you could use an external line-shuffling tool (like `sort -R` or `shuf` on Linux) to shuffle the file. Then, the 1000 repeated lines of some examples would be evenly spread among all the other (repeated) examples, a friendlier arrangement for dense-vector learning.

In any case, I would try leaving out repetition entirely, or shuffling repetitions, and evaluate which steps are really helping on whatever the true end goal is.